# QGIS - SAGA Majority Filter creating huge output files

Tags: qgis, saga

I am trying to perform a workflow that I have made in QGIS which operates on very large rasters (38244x62124).

Leading up to this, I have been able to run various GDAL tools if I specify that the output image is to be compressed via LZW, and if I don't, then the image balloons from about 200MB to 20GB.

I am hitting the same problem when running the "Majority Filter" tool from SAGA. The image is exploding up to the order of GB, which quickly fills up the drive I have to work on and halts the entire workflow.

I have limited space on the machine that I am using. Is there a way to tell SAGA to make a compressed image as an output, similar to how you can compress the image using GDAL?

Comment: Is standalone SAGA an option for you?

Comment: @Kazuhito Not really, this is part of a QGIS Modeller chain. If it is not possible to use the modeller then I am just going to write something using Python (rasterio/numpy/scipy)